# JavaScript __dopostback gets called by clicking anywhere on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have an html table in my asp.net application. When a td element is clicked, I store td element id in a hidden field using JavaScript. After that, I am forcing __dopostback from JavaScript to use the hidden field value in code behind.

HTML:

```
<td id="m1" onclick="">Jan</td>
<td id="m2" onclick="">Feb</td>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.window td').on('click', function () {
        var idName = this.id;
        var selectedid = idName.substring(1);
        console.log(selectedid);
        $('#hidden').val(selectedid);
        _doPostBack(idName , '');
});
```

Now when I click on anywhere in the page, __doPostBack gets called. But I want it to be called only when td element is clicked.

How do I prevent __doPostBack from getting called when user clicks anywhere else?

Comment: can  you provide us the live demo url?

Comment: Does the page include other `<td>`s within a `class="window"` that the selector could match? "*Click on anywhere*" suggests the page may be using `<table>`s for layout structure. The selector may just need to be altered to be more specific to match only the `<td>`s you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had few more tables in the page with class="window". When I changed the name, it worked.